# Declare Initial Value of BigDecimal Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, bigdecimal

I want to declare a `BigDecimal` `Array` with initial value `0` like this:

```
BigDecimal[] val = {0,0,0};
```

but it's not working. Please help me to know how to declare `BigDecimal` `array` with initial value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use Arrays.fill() as that will would for any number of zeros (or any other BigDecimal value you like)  This works because BigDecimal is immutable, don't do this for mutable values ;)

```
BigDecimal[] val = new BigDecimal[N];
Arrays.fill(val, BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solition, actually. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the predefined `BigDecimal.ZERO` constant:

```
BigDecimal[] val = { BigDecimal.ZERO,
                    BigDecimal.ZERO,
                    BigDecimal.ZERO };
```

Answer (score 5):

```
BigDecimal[] val = {new BigDecimal(0),new BigDecimal(0),new BigDecimal(0)};
```

BigDecimal is an object, not a primitive type, so you need to create new instances of the object in order to fill an array with them.

It's no different from if you do:

```
BigDecimal val = 0;  // Fails
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(0);  // Succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.fill(Object[], Object)` with `BigDecimal.ZERO`, because `BigDecimal`'s are immutable. Thus you don't need to create a new instance for every array element.

```
 BigDecimal[] val = new BigDecimal[10]; // 10 for example - chosse the size you want
 Arrays.fill(val, BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the `BigDecimal` value this way:

```
BigDecimal amt = null;

amt = new BigDecimal("110000");
```

Comment: This doesn't add useful information, which isn't already included in the other answers.